# CRUD operation using Umbraco MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco7, umbraco6

Can anyone have idea about how to develop CRUD using UmbracoCms with MVC 3?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to give more details about your problem, give an example or share some code because now its to difficult to know the exact problem

Comment: The Problem is already listed and If u can understand I want to create CRUD (Create,Read,Update and Delete) using Umbraco MVC with Razor Engine

Comment: umbraco.tv and youtube

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different approaches for putting data into umbraco through the frontend, most common way is through [surface controllers](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/surface-controllers) another approach is through client side code and the umbraco [web api](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/)